# PostgreSQL not taking full advantage of all computing resources

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance, st-dwithin, cross-join-lateral

Basically I have one table buildings_by_cell_300m, About 2490000 rows. I want to statistic all the geom information within 50 meters of each geom.
I am doing:

```
CREATE TABLE gbmi.bn_by_cell_300m AS (

SELECT DISTINCT
    bldg1."id" AS id1,
    bldg1."geom" AS geom1,
    bldg1."calc_lucc_area" AS lucc_area1,
    bldg1."building_height" AS building_height1,
    bldg1."cell_id",
    bldg1."cell_geom",
    bldg1."cell_area",
    bldg2."id" AS id2,
    bldg2."geom" AS geom2,
    bldg2."calc_lucc_area" AS geom_area2,
    bldg2."building_height" AS building_height2,
    st_distance(bldg1.geom::geography, bldg2.geom::geography, false) AS distance
FROM
    gbmi.buildings_by_cell_300m AS bldg1
 CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT id, geom, calc_lucc_area, building_height
            FROM gbmi.buildings_by_cell_300m
            ) AS bldg2
            WHERE ST_DWITHIN(geography(bldg1.geom), geography(bldg2.geom), 50) 
AND NOT ST_Equals(bldg1."geom"::geometry, bldg2."geom"::geometry)
            );
```

My problem is that it's taking forever. I ran it for like 50 hours and still got nowhere, and the most outrageous thing is that my supercomputer's computing resources are only utilized by 4 percent. What can I do to make use of my supercomputer. I've tuned the relevant parameters in postgresql.conf to be large enough, but it didn't work.

What can I do?

[image][image]

[image]

Some of the parameters of postgresql.conf are set as follows, other information not listed are default parameters.

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 20            # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 400GB          # min 128kB
work_mem = 200GB                # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 1.0      # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
maintenance_work_mem = 2047MB       # min 1MB
effective_io_concurrency =300       # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 96       # (change requires restart)
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 48    # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 6    # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_workers = 96       # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
                    # can be used in parallel operations
full_page_writes = on           # recover from partial page writes
checkpoint_timeout = 55min      # range 30s-1d
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9  # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
max_wal_size = 500GB
min_wal_size = 4GB
random_page_cost = 1.1          # same scale as above
effective_cache_size = 400GB
default_statistics_target = 500 # range 1-10000

log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
logging_collector = on      # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog

autovacuum = on         # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
autovacuum_max_workers = 4      # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
autovacuum_naptime = 1min       # time between autovacuum runs
lc_messages = 'Chinese (Simplified)_China.936'          # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'Chinese (Simplified)_China.936'          # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'Chinese (Simplified)_China.936'           # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'Chinese (Simplified)_China.936'              # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.simple'
```

Comment: Please add the information as text, not images. Why do you think those configuration settings are good? Have you tried a different, more efficient join type?(!) Have you tried limiting the columns?

Comment: HI, bugmenot123, I'm very sorry, I'm new to postgresql and I thought that setting the configuration parameters large enough would be efficient enough. Some of the parameters have been added, those not added are the default parameters.

Comment: This feels silly for me `AND NOT ST_Equals(bldg1."geom"::geometry, bldg2."geom"::geometry)` because you could as well compare the ids `where id1 != id2`. Or can the same building have many ids?

Comment: Well, better make sure you did not tune things worse (eg is your DB really on a SSD?). https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ is a good start. Make sure all your geometry/geography casts in queries don't end up without indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*PostgreSQL* is **single-threaded by design** - and necessity; RDBS aim to be [ACID](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/acid-compliance-what-it-means-and-why-you-should-care) compliant, and cross-thread transaction safety is neigh impossible to implement¹.

Starting with PostgreSQL 10, the planner *may* start up multiple worker threads if it deems a workload distribution to be safe, and your query may be eligible for a parallel table scan - but you would still not get anywhere near to fully utilizing your hardware resources.

*Generally, if you need distributed computing over data inside an RDBS, partition your requests on the application side and issue fenced queries to get executed in multiple connections, then gather results in your application for post-processing.*

---

That being said, you attempt to scan and process 2.5M rows with non-trivial proximity operations on each, and ask to return `2.5M * <average_building_count_in_proximity>` rows.

Since you mention '*statistics*' you may want to define their values and compute them per row, rather than simply gathering neighboring buildings:

```
SELECT
  bldg1.*,  -- choose base columns explicitly if needed
  stats.*
FROM
  gbmi.buildings_by_cell_300m AS bldg1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      AVG(bldg2."building_height") AS "average_building_height"  -- example for returning a single statistical value per row in bldg1
    FROM
      gbmi.buildings_by_cell_300m AS bldg2
    WHERE
      ST_DWithin(bldg2.geom::GEOGRAPHY, bldg1.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 50)
      AND
      bldg2.id <> bldg1.id
  ) AS stats
;
```

*For simple set-parametric operations (`AVG`, `SUM` etc.) you can use a plain `[LEFT] JOIN` in conjunction with a `GROUP BY`, but the sequential scan and atomic operations per row in the above query may more easily spawn worker threads - you'd need to decide based on your requirements, and then test performance across approaches.*

Here, `AVG(bldg2."building_height") AS "average_building_height"` is an example of a statistical (*single*) value that can be computed per table row - across all matched spatial neighbors.

**Notes:**

- `ST_Equals` is comparably costly, and unnecessary; for self-joins it is much more performant (and idiomatic) to exclude by numeric `id`
- `DISTINCT` is a non-trivial operation, and seems to be completely unnecessary here; generally, try to favor `GROUP BY` on large result sets
- depending on the distribution pattern in your data you may find a traditional `GIST` index to outperform the `SP-GIST` index - buildings are an unlikely candidate for efficient spatial partitioning; either way, it is crucial that the index is

  ```
  ... USING [SP-]GIST ( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) );
  ```

---

¹ It certainly is *possible*, but thread-safety is extremely complex already without high-level ACID compliance in mind, and a complete rewrite of the core engine is dwarfed only by refactoring an existing code-base designed to be single-threaded. And lastly, the overhead of the inherently complex architecture needed to ensure transactional safety may not produce the performance boost one may expect.

Comment: Making sure the spatial index is on the cast `geography` is probably critical for ST_DWithin performance

Comment: @Vince probably a good idea to emphasize that. From the `EXPLAIN` plans above I take it that the cast is indeed covered, though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice very much, geozelot. I've removed the st_equal function as you suggested, but it still doesn't seem to improve anything. What I'm wondering is that when I run other query statements, my running memory is utilized as expected, which should prove that my configuration parameters are fine, but why this query doesn't work at all, and the compute resource utilization is still only 4 percent.

Comment: Thanks, Vince. I have confirmed that the index is valid.